# Problems Installing Ubuntu on old MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on an old MacBook Pro 2.1 but am struggling.

Firstly, the CD ROM seems pretty flakey and doesn’t appear to be working.

I then tried to install it via a bootable USB stick using rEFInd (as the option to boot from USB doesn’t appear when I hit the OPTION key when booting up). I get to the initial rEFInd screen where I can choose to boot from the USB stick, but when I select the USB option, a load of errors appear on the screen and that’s as far as I get (sorry I don't have a screengrab).

I’ve tried creating bootable 32 and 64bit versions of Ubuntu but I still encounter the same errors with rEFInd.

I also considered using Unetbootin to do a hard disk install, but the hard disk wouldn’t partition, no matter what size partition I chose. (I'm guessing the disk is pretty fragmented and can't find a clean enough space to create the partition?).

Can anyone suggest an alternative way of installing Ubuntu?

Comment: Maybe you should add information about what Ubuntu version you are going to install to get better answers.
Also if you are going to install MacOS and Ubuntu parallel or only Ubuntu?

Usually this kind of struggles happen because your PC is simply not compatible I'm affraid

Comment: Does it work to just boot into Ubuntu using a Live-USB or say "Test Ubuntu" instead of "Install Ubuntu"?

Comment: Apols. I'm trying to install Ubuntu v16.04. 

I don't mind installing Ubuntu over the original OS, or having it running in parallel with the existing OSX version. 

Re your last point, it doesn't boot from USB at all.

Comment: Ok. Did you check before if your 'old' system fulfills the standart requirements for Ubuntu16.04? I'm clearly not an expert but I'ld say if it isn't even able to boot the live system correctly than it would be quite difficult to install it, I'm sorry.

Ofcourse there would be some possibiities but ... for example you could remove the harddrive and try to istall it using another PC and stuff like that

Comment: The Mac easily fulfills the standard requirements.

Comment: Maybe you could look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770799/installation-ubuntu-14-04-15-10-16-04-not-working-on-macbookpro-3-1-boot-freeze?rq=1). I know its not the same version but maybe it works for you, too